# How to call private flow execution from main flow when Quartz scheduler in configured?

Tags: mule

```
<flow name="Flow1">
   <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="ReadQ1" cronExpression="* 30 15 * * ?">
     <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
     <quartz:job-endpoint address="jms://Q1"/>
     </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
   </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
   <component>
     <singleton-object class="MyComponenet"/>
   </component>
   <choice>
      <when expression="payload==200" evaluator="groovy">
         <flow-ref name="Flow2"/>
      </when>
   </choice>
</flow>
<flow name="Flow2">
  <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="Q2"/>
  <component class="AnotherComponent"/>
  <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Q3"/>
</flow>
```

I expect Flow1 to execute at the defined quartz schedule(15:30). 
And based on the payload return from MyComponent, I refer Flow2 to execute. 
But Flow2 executes even before Flow1 is triggered.

How do I implement the flows so that Flow2 is always called from Flow1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use flow-ref in flow1, then make your flow2 to sub-flow. Then remove the jms-inbound endpoint from flow2

```
<sub-flow name="Flow2">
  <component class="AnotherComponent"/>
  <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Q3"/>
</sub-flow>
```

And replace also flow3 with sub-flow if you want to use flow-ref.

Another option is to replace you flow-ref call with `<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Q2"/>` and keep your flow2 as it is in your example.

Comment: In that case Q2 will contain message payload 200 which is a rubbish message that will pollute my business message queue - Q2.

Comment: All I am trying to achieve in a more crooked way is this..........Queue Q1 message should be dequeued and delivered to a component which has webservice invocation targets. If those services are unavailable I lose the message from Q1 to DLQ.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying. I guess that the queues don't do the trick as the inbound queue tries to poll the queue immediately? Could you save the objects to a list into a session property or so to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Flow2 is not private. To make it private you have to remove the inbound endpoint.

Without taking that approach the flow won't ba callable from a flow-ref element.

With that said you can use 3 approaches

1. Sub-flow (introduced in mule 3.2 and currently recommended): it will behave as a subroutine sharing exception the context of the invoking flow (e.g. exception strategy and threading pool)
2. Private flow (for mule 3.1.x): it will create a new flow with is own context that will handle the message generated by the invoking flow
3. Publish the message to queue (e.g. the jms Q2 or a vm one) and consume it from your current flow

Answer (score 0):

You can declare Flow2's initial state as "stopped":

This will prevent Flow2 to run before Flow1 (Or to run at all).

Then you can programmatically start it with a groovy script:

```
if (muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('Flow2').isStopped())
{
    muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('Flow2').start()
}
```

Once you start it the jms queue will start polling.

I hope this helps.